# Write a regular expression to match phone numbers

Tags: r, regex

I have to write a regular expression to match phone numbers. A phone number can be in any one of the following forms:

```
(123) 456-7890
(123)456-7890
1234567890
123 456 7890
123-456-7890
123.456.7890
```

I have to store the regular expression in a variable called re5.

The test cases I have to pass are here: [link](https://regex101.com/r/zZ7cIV/1)

I just need the re5 = "..." part, where I need the correct code for the ... part.

This is what I have so far..

```
re5 = "^(\\d{3}|\\(\\d{3}\\))([ ]?\\d{3}[-]|[ ]\\".
```

I don't know what is going wrong. Thanks!

Different that other answers due to test cases in link above.

Comment: Try [`^(?:\(\d{3}\) ?\d{3}-|\d{6}|\d{3}([ .-])\d{3}\1)\d{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/zZ7cIV/3)

Comment: @jogo It's not I tried it already.

Comment: Can you just get all the numbers from each string? `library(stringr); 
paste0(str_extract_all(phone_string, regex("[0-9]"), T), collapse = '')`

Comment: So what did not work in the thread linked by jogo?

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks! That worked!

Comment: @erocoar no but User: ctwheels got it!

Comment: @erocoar Thanks though

Comment: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone+number

Comment: (\d{3})\W{0,2}(\d{3})\W{0,1}(\d{4}) You can try this too. Seems short.  You can look at the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/l1tdot/1)

Comment: \b\W{0,1}(\d{3})\W{0,2}(\d{3})\W{0,1}(\d{4})\b

Answer (score 0):

This passes all your [tests](https://regex101.com/r/zZ7cIV/1/tests):

```
^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})(?: |([-.])?)\d{3}(?(1)\1|[ -.]?)\d{4}$
```

Bear in mind that this uses PCRE-specific syntax, so you'll need to [enable that using `perl = TRUE`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html)